# AWS s3 downloading files taking too long in Swift

Tags: swift, api, amazon-s3

I am making an app and it is supposed to get images and pdfs from an s3 bucket but it is taking wayy longer than expected. Is there a way like make it download everything at the same time cause I think right now my code is downloading each file individual and then starting the next one only after the previous file is downloaded.

I tried some stuff online but couldnt get it to download concurrently. Can someone help?

```swift
func getImageFromAPI(selectedKey: String, result: [String:[String: [String]]]?, output: [Hall]) async {
    let directory = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first
    let directory2 = directory?.appendingPathComponent("\(selectedKey)/")
    
    do {
        try FileManager.default.createDirectory(at: directory2!, withIntermediateDirectories: false)
    } catch let error {
        print("could not create directory", error)
    }
    
    if let unwrapped = result {
        for key in unwrapped.keys {
            let newkey = key.replacingOccurrences(of: " ", with: "_")
            let path = directory2?.appendingPathComponent("\(newkey).jpg")
            if checkIfFileExists(selectedKey: selectedKey, key: newkey, path: path) != true {
                let complete_api = "inserturl" + selectedKey + "/" + "\(newkey).jpg"
                let url = URL(string: complete_api)!
                let image = try? await downloadWithAsync(url: url)
                
                guard let data = image?.jpegData(compressionQuality: 1.0) else {
                    return
                }
                
                do {
                    try data.write(to: path!)
                } catch let error {
                    print("error saving \(error)")
                }
            }
        }
        
        for key in output {
            let newkey = key.name.replacingOccurrences(of: " ", with: "_")
            let path = directory2?.appendingPathComponent("\(newkey).jpg")
            // + "/" + "\(newkey).jpg"
            if checkIfFileExists(selectedKey: selectedKey, key: newkey, path: path) != true {
                let complete_api = "inserturl" + selectedKey + "/" + "\(newkey).jpg"
                let url = URL(string: complete_api)!
                
                let image = try? await downloadWithAsync(url: url)
                
                guard let data = image?.jpegData(compressionQuality: 1.0) else {
                    return
                }
                
                do {
                    try data.write(to: path!)
                } catch let error {
                    print("error saving \(error)")
                }
            }
            
            for i in 1...key.sections! {
                let pdfpath = directory2?.appendingPathComponent("\(newkey)_Menu_\(i).pdf")
                if checkIfFileExists(selectedKey: selectedKey, key: newkey, path: pdfpath) != true {
                    let complete_api = "inserturl" + selectedKey + "/" + "\(newkey)_Menu_\(i).pdf"
                    let pdfFile = try? Data.init(contentsOf: URL(string: complete_api)!)
                    
                    do {
                        try pdfFile?.write(to: pdfpath!, options: .atomic)
                    } catch {
                        print("error saving pdf")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        images_loaded = true
    }
}
```

Comment: https://www.avanderlee.com/concurrency/task-groups-in-swift/

Comment: I tried it doesnt work or I am doing it wrong